Prioritising network calls in a native android built livestreaming application
here is my usecase. I work on a network intense livestreaming application. When a user is watching a livestream, he also is watching the livechats below the player and many manny other network calls are made in the background. As the user has a certain bandwidth I guess these network calls might hinder the buffering of livestream data. How do I prioritize the livestream datastream download above others ? Do you guys have a certain resource for such livestream app mobile system design or any other optimisation usecase, engineering talk etc ?
The real problem is to talk between different libraries like websockets, exoplayer, ads module and retrofit and communicate for prioritizing network calls among all of them combined. eg: I want to give priority to my ads and livestream exoplayer network calls more than others.
